# Generic object names not being serialized when using openapi generator for a java client

Tags: java, openapi, swagger-codegen

I generated a java client using openapi generate version 5.0.0 using all the defaults other than model packages and so forth.

I have it rendering properly in a swagger editor like this.

[image]

The specific yaml for this component looks like this.

```
components:
  schemas:
    WorkItem:
      properties:
        workitems:
          type: array
          items:
            properties:
              json:
                type: object
                additionalProperties:
                  type: string
```

The sample code using the client looks like this.

```
    ApiKeyAuth ApiKeyAuth = (ApiKeyAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("ApiKeyAuth");
    ApiKeyAuth.setApiKey(result.getToken());

    WorkItem workItem = new WorkItem();

    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("test1", "test1");
    map.put("test2", "test2");
    map.put("test3", "test3");

    workItem.addWorkitemsItem(map);


    apiInstance.addWorkItem("3", "9", workItem);
```

Yet when I log the info it shows that the payload in the request body looks like this.

```
{"workitems":[{"test2":"test2","test3":"test3","test1":"test1"}]}
```

Instead of what the swagger shows above. I was expecting it to render out the objects name. In this case it is a generic map instead of a "json" named object. Is there something I am doing wrong in the way I am structuring the openapi?

If I try to make it more specific without using additionalproperties, the client still resorts back to using a generic object in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use a singleton map instead of a regular map.

```
workItem.addWorkitemsItem(Collections.singletonMap("json", map));
```